# CodeIgniter: Looping through Users to Log-out Inactive Users Based on Session via Cron

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, cron

I have a CodeIgniter platform where I want to log out users via cron daily due to inactivity

Background:

- I want to do this via Cron, because I'm assuming that if it's just AJAX or php then it might not work as a request would need to be made in order to trigger the log out.
- I only want to do a logout every day.
- I've been tinkering with CodeIgniter's session methods, but I'm failing to see how I can both loop through users and target them based off of session data.

I Have some rudimentary code below

```
$users_sql = "SELECT * FROM `users`";
$users_result = $this->db->query($users_sql)->result();      

foreach($users_result as $user){
    $this->session->set_userdata("user_id",$user->id); //set user id  
    $user_session_data = $this->session->userdata('last_activity'); // Do I need to have some kind of additional cookie here?
    // Check last session stuff and logout if either midnight and no activity
}
```

Any help pointing me in the right direction would be very much appreciated!

Comment: I might be missing something here, but why setting a standard session expiration of X hours in the session configuration is not an alternative? It's a lot cleaner and easier (just change one config parameter)

Answer (score 1):

I believe but have not confirmed or tested that you can use the session library method `gc($maxlifetime)` to accomplish your goal. Every driver for the CI session class must define this method so it doesn't matter if you're using files, database, or any of the other flavors.

"gc" stands for Garbage Collector and it will delete all session data older than the current time minus $maxlifetime. Passing a `$maxlifetime` value of 0 (zero) should delete all sessions created before the current `time()`.

So, create a simple controller that loads the `session` library and run this line of code.

```
$this->session->gc(0);
```

All the required looping and other business in handled for you.